# systemd timer fails to start (Invalid argument) when using UTC time

Tags: linux, systemd

Here is my timer:

```
[Unit]
Description=Do whatever

[Timer]
OnCalendar=daily UTC

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

It fails to start with the following error:

```
Failed to start mytimer.timer: Unit mytimer.timer failed to load: Invalid argument. See system logs and 'systemctl status mytimer.timer' for details.
```

Sadly `systemctl status` doesn't add any clarity to the error message

But, if I remove the UTC literal, it works perfectly:

```
[Unit]
Description=Do whatever

[Timer]
OnCalendar=daily

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

What am I doing wrong?

[This document](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.time.html#) describes the format accepted by `OnCalendar`, and it shows that UTC can be used.

Yes, I tried using quotes - doesn't help. I also tried using the normalized form - same thing

Versions:

- OS: CentOS 7
- kernel: 3.10.0-042stab113.21
- systemd: systemd-219-19.el7_2.9.x86_64

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`OnCalendar=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.time.html) with any timestamp suffixed by `UTC` requires systemd 228 or later. This functionality was added in systemd 228.

From the systemd [changelog](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/NEWS):

> CHANGES WITH 228:
>
> ...
>
> - Wherever systemd expects a calendar timestamp specification
>           (like in journalctl's --since= and --until= switches) UTC
>           timestamps are now supported. Timestamps suffixed with "UTC"
>           are now considered to be in Universal Time Coordinated
>           instead of the local timezone. Also, timestamps may now
>           optionally be specified with sub-second accuracy. Both of
>           these additions also apply to recurring calendar event
>           specification, such as OnCalendar= in timer units.

Comment: It is a best practice to run servers in UTC time whenever possible anyway, so you may find that that is an effective workaround.